# Cannot get records for particular meeting

Tags: adobe-connect

Cannot figure out how to properly send request to get all records, which are corresponding to the meeting.
From this request  `mysite.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=sco-info&sco-id=1087877981`

I get such response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<results>
  <status code="ok"/>
  <sco account-id="1051298934" disabled="" display-seq="0" folder-id="1057190786" icon="meeting" lang="en" max-retries="" sco-id="1087877981" source-sco-id="1051270965" type="meeting" version="3">
    <date-begin>2013-08-20T03:15:00.000-07:00</date-begin>
    <date-created>2013-08-20T03:30:04.200-07:00</date-created>
    <date-end>2013-08-20T04:15:00.000-07:00</date-end>
    <date-modified>2013-08-20T06:39:45.927-07:00</date-modified>
    <name>DevTeam Meeting 2</name>
    <url-path>/devmeeting2/</url-path>
    <update-linked-item>true</update-linked-item>
  </sco>
  <source-sco>
    <source-sco account-id="1051298934" disabled="" display-seq="0" folder-id="1051270964" icon="meeting" lang="en" max-retries="" sco-id="1051270965" source-sco-id="-8888" type="meeting" version="1">
      <date-created>2012-05-15T14:09:07.453-07:00</date-created>
      <date-modified>2013-08-13T16:33:57.600-07:00</date-modified>
      <name>Default Meeting Template</name>
      <url-path>/defaultmeetingtemplate/</url-path>
    </source-sco></source-sco>
  </results>
```

Where I see `folder-id="1057190786"` and `sco-id="1087877981"`, but when I'm trying to get records for this meeting, using folder-id or sco-id according to [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/connect/9.0/webservices/WS26a970dc1da1c212717c4d5b12183254583-8000_SP1.html#WS11d22296f5cfec5e-3c656138140554dc69e-7ffe) with requests

```
mysite.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=list-recordings&folder-id=1057190786
```

or

```
mysite.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=list-recordings&folder-id=1087877981
```

I receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<results>
  <status code="invalid">
    <invalid field="action" type="enum" subcode="no-such-item"/>
  </status>
</results>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use another API [method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/connect/9.0/webservices/WS26a970dc1da1c212717c4d5b12183254583-8000_SP1.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a171ddf77-7e59_SP1) to get the recordings. They listed in the "scos" container, "url-path" element is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the sco-contents method...

/api/xml?action=sco-contents&filter-icon=archive&sco-id=1087877981

Answer (score 0):

1. Get your meeting contents calling **sco-contents**
2. You will find your records in those **sco** with **icon="archive"**

Don't use "list-recordings" as is not available anymore.

> Reference (Sep. 20, 2016)
>   Provides a list of recordings (FLV and MP4) for a specified folder. **The service and hence the API is no longer available.**

[Docs here.](https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-connect/webservices/topics/action-reference.html)